# javascript, how to deal with strings with strange characters

Tags: javascript, unicode

I have to process a file with strange characters in a string. This string is in two files where they are identical (created by another program, the name refers to what the user has set in that program).

The problem is that when I read that string from two different files, I get different readings with javascript.

It happens in my computer where I suspect I don't have these characters installed, but also in the user computer where I assume he is seeing another set of characters (but equal in any case, that's the thing). Yet, both computers have the same problem.

When opening the two files they look the same, the two strings appear in one file as

```
sample� Sa0S +
sample  Sa0S �
```

and in the other file as

```
sample� Sa0S +
sample  Sa0S �
```

This is, identical. But when I read them in javascript and console.log both, then I get this

```
(file 1)    Identification type sample  Sa0S �
(file 1)    Identification type sample� Sa0S +
(file 2)    sample��� Sa0S +
(file 2)    sample� Sa0S +
```

And this breaks the program since I expect to have the same strings

The first one comes from this regex, even though

```
var pieces = [];
pieces = lines[0].split("\t");
for (var i in pieces) {
  switch (true) {
    case /^\"?Identification type\s..*\"?\s?$/.test(pieces[i]):
    console.log(pieces[i])
```

And the second one is just

```
for (let i in lines) {
  pieces = lines[i].split("\t");
  console.log(pieces[some_index])
```

So the problem is that ... well, I don't know what's going on. I am about to say to the user that chooses simple characters in the first program, but I'd like to understand what's going on here.

Comment: What is purpose for using `for..in` loop to iterate array?

Comment: Not really relevant here, it is a way to navigate through the columns or lines of the files.